# No permissions granted on Android emulator

Tags: android, permissions, location

I wrote a simple Hello World app to debug some permissions problem I'm having.

The problem is that my app can't obtain permissions to use anything. Yes, I'm using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

and yes I put that tag right under `<manifest>` in AndroidManifest.xml

If I remove all `<uses-permission>` tags from the manifest and go to `Settings > Apps > TestApp`, it says **No permissions requested**

If I put the tags back in, it says **No permissions granted**

If I debug on an actual device, it says the permissions are there so it looks like this problem is only occurring on the emulator! However, it also works when I run the `android-play-location/LocationUpdates` project from developer.android.com using the same emulator so maybe there's something wrong with my project setup.

Any ideas?

- IDE: Android Studio
- Virtual Device: Nexus_5_API_23
- OS: guest Ubuntu 14.04 running on host OS X Yosemite (VMWare Fusion)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I put the tags back in, it says No permissions granted

That is because you are testing on Android 6.0, and your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 23.

> If I debug on an actual device, it says the permissions are there so it looks like this problem is only occurring on the emulator!

No, it is occurring only on Android 6.0+.

> However, it also works when I run the android-play-location/LocationUpdates project from developer.android.com using the same emulator so maybe there's something wrong with my project setup.

That project probably has a `targetSdkVersion` below 23.

`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is governed by [the Android 6.0 runtime permission system](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html). Either update your app to use that system, or drop your `targetSdkVersion` below 23 until you are ready to do so.

Answer (score 4):

just request location permission if you are running on M

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION);
}else{
    //Do things as usual
}
```

wait for a result in

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] result){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, result);


    if(requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION && result[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        //do things as usual init map or something else when location permission is granted
    }
}
```